# Time formats for NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have datetime values coming into my app from a web service. The format is as follows:

`2013-03-24T09:45:00.000-04:00`

I need only the time from this value. I am using `NSDateFormatter` and am setting the date format as follows:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

and when I do this I get a rather cryptic runtime error. However, I have no errors when I use the following (though it doesn't satisfy my requirement):

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssz"];
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *originalDateString = @"2013-03-24T09:45:00.000-04:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssz"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:originalDateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: @HotLicks I posted the code after getting the proper output. Can you please verify this.

Comment: Is there a method in the NSDateFormatter to convert 24 hour time formats to 12 with AM/PM?

Comment: @Vivian Yes there is set the format to @"hh:mm:ss a". But before continuing you should read the date formatting guide https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: Also note that the `ZZZZZ` timezone format required for the `-99:99` timezone strings only works under iOS 6. It is not supported under iOS 5 or earlier. And lastly, you really should set the formatter's locale to the `en_US_POSIX` locale when parsing fixed format date strings. Of course you want the default locale when converting the `NSDate` to a user visible date string.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your response, can you explain the fixed format date strings. Did you mean that the timezone the server is going to send would be always same or the dateFormat is fixed one. Usually the date strings that I receive from webservice may have different timezones. And I have always used the above style for almost all occassions and it always worked (not talking about "z" or "ZZZZZ" here) but using the en_US_POSIX. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you use date formater to retrieve a NSDate instance and from there do you own formating.

```
NSSTring *dateString = "2013-03-24T09:45:00.000-04:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *dateFromWebApp = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Haven't tested tho but it should work.

Cheers